# Change Null from SQL to 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This question has been asked a couple of times on this site, however none of the solutions have worked for me.

I am running a query within a query:

```
 //this query is to count variables
$sql = "SELECT variabletype, COUNT(variabletype) AS value_occurrence FROM variable GROUP BY variabletype ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC";
$vars_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$pos = array();

while($vars = mysqli_fetch_array($vars_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {

  //each variable has many different values, some positive, some negative, in this query I am trying to understand of the values found, how many of them are positive and pushing the result into an array. 
 $times_positive_qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT variable.variabletype, COUNT(value.valueid) AS positive_occurrence FROM variable INNER JOIN value On variable.variableid=value.variableid WHERE variable.variabletype = '" .$vars['variabletype']. "' AND value.valuelift>0.00 AND value.valuesignificant=1 GROUP BY variable.variabletype ORDER BY positive_occurrence DESC");
 $times_positive = mysqli_fetch_array($times_positive_qry, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $pos[] = $times_positive['positive_occurrence'];

}
```

My result is:

```
var s1 = ["10","3","2","3","4","5","3","3","2","1",null,"2","2",null,"4","3","3","2","2","2","1","1","1",null,"1",null,null,null,"1","1",null,"1","1",null,"3",null,"1","1","1",null]
```

You'll notice that in some of the results are being returned as **null**, meaning there is no positive value for a particular variable.  Anyway I can replace the nulls with 0's?  I've tried `IFNULL` and `COALESCE`, but they have NOT worked.

Ultimately I need the nulls to be 0's because I am graphing the array and the graph will not display if I have null values.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean they not worked? what is your query with `COALESCE`?

Comment: @Alexander I received the same output with COALESCE

Comment: I have 2 questions in my comment

Comment: @Alexander `SELECT variable.variabletype, COALESCE(COUNT(value.valueid),0) AS positive_occurrence FROM variable INNER JOIN value On variable.variableid=value.variableid WHERE variable.variabletype = '" .$vars['variabletype']. "' AND value.valuelift>0.00 AND value.valuesignificant=1 GROUP BY variable.variabletype ORDER BY positive_occurrence DESC`

Comment: @user2828701 you are coalescing the wrong column, if you look at your result closely you see that only the first of two values turns null "sometimes", but that is not the `COUNT(variabletype)` but `variabletype` itself; but to be honest, that is just an assumption, because you never show how that result string you got in s1 gets built...

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I am starting to think my result is not what I want in the first place.  I think I may need to go back to the drawing board here...

Answer (score 1):

Use `IFNULL` function like

```
IFNULL(your_column,0)
```

From your comment, you are doing `coalesce` wrongly. it should be like below. Cause
if `valueid` is `null` then `COUNT(value.valueid)` anyways will be 0 (try a sample to see that like `select count(null) as total`).

```
SELECT IFNULL(variable.variabletype,0), <-- Change Here
COUNT(value.valueid) AS positive_occurrence
FROM variable 
INNER JOIN value 
On 
variable.variableid=value.variableid 
WHERE variable.variabletype = '" .$vars['variabletype']. "' 
AND 
value.valuelift>0.00 
AND 
value.valuesignificant=1
GROUP BY variable.variabletype 
ORDER BY positive_occurrence DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
"SELECT variable.variabletype, COUNT(value.valueid)..."

"SELECT variable.variabletype, isnull(COUNT(value.valueid),0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the isnull function

ISNULL(YOUR_VAR, 0)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: Probably not a good idea to post MS Technet docs in response to a MYSQL question, the ISNULL function isn't the same.

Comment: @SteveMartin, it's just syntactical change but the concept is same. be it `ifnull` or `isnull`. Stop doing the downvoting nuisence.

Comment: @Rahul, a syntactical change on a programming site is a big deal. I downvoted because your answer was incorrect.
In the light of your edit I have redacted my downvote. See how the system works to improve the quality of answers!
Not quite sure why you upvoted this one as it is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ISNULL() function

```
ISNULL(COUNT(value.valueid),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want you can manually go through your php array and do string replace,or if you have access to the database you can just do something like 
`"update variable set value=0 where value is NULL;"`

Comment: I tried `$pos_array = str_replace("null", "0", $pos);` and `$pos_array = str_replace("null", 0, $pos);` the nulls are gone, but I am left with just double quotes like "", so while it is removing the nulls, it is not replacing with a 0.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is with the second query:

```
$vars_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$pos = array();

while($vars = mysqli_fetch_array($vars_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //each variable has many different values, some positive, some negative, in this query I am trying to understand of the values found, how many of them are positive and pushing the result into an array. 
    $times_positive_qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT variable.variabletype, COUNT(value.valueid) AS positive_occurrence FROM variable INNER JOIN value On variable.variableid=value.variableid WHERE variable.variabletype = '" .$vars['variabletype']. "' AND value.valuelift>0.00 AND value.valuesignificant=1 GROUP BY variable.variabletype ORDER BY positive_occurrence DESC");         $times_positive = mysqli_fetch_array($times_positive_qry, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $pos[] = $times_positive['positive_occurrence'];
}
```

The problem is that your `WHERE` clause can eliminate all results.  That means the entire result set can be null.  **You'll get a result set of zero rows.**  You'll need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to ensure you always get a row back.

Your query string for `$times_positive_qry` should look like this:

```
"SELECT variable.variabletype, 
    COUNT(value.valueid) AS positive_occurrence 
FROM variable 
LEFT JOIN value 
    ON variable.variableid = value.variableid 
WHERE variable.variabletype = '" .$vars['variabletype']. "' 
    AND ((value.valuelift > 0.00 AND value.valuesignificant = 1)
        OR
    (value.valuelift IS NULL AND value.valuesignificant IS NULL))    
GROUP BY variable.variabletype 
ORDER BY positive_occurrence DESC"
```

Note: You will have problems if there are legitimate cases where variables can have `value.valuelift IS NULL AND value.valuesignificant IS NULL` be true.  You may need to add `value.variableid IS NULL`... it's difficult to say without looking at the data.

Comment: your answer looks promising, thanks for taking a look.  Let me work through this and see what I come back with.